# ¿En qué posición del vector se encuentra "Ricardo Gutierrez”?

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

Programa que lea `x` cantidad de nombres y apellidos y me muestre en qué oficina se encuentra el empleado “Ricardo Gutiérrez”

Se usa burbujeo para realizar la búsqueda. Este es mi código:

```
Algoritmo AF

    Escribir "Ingrese Cantidad "
    Leer cantidad
    
    Dimension Nombres[cantidad]
    Dimension Apellidos[cantidad]
    
    Para contador <-1 Hasta cantidad Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir "ingrese Nombre"
        Leer Nombres[contador]    *//Aqui me aparece un problema*
        Escribir "ingrese Apellido"
        Leer Apellidos[contador]
    Fin Para
    
    Para contador1<-1 Hasta cantidad Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Si Nombres[contador1] y Apellidos[contador1] == "Ricardo Gutierrez"  Entonces
            aux=contador
        Fin Si
    Fin Para
    Escribir "Ricardo Gutierrez estaba en la oficina", aux
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algunos errores, el primero por el que consultas es porque aunque declaras `Dimension`, esta no tiene un tipo asignado por lo cual arroja error, esto se solucionaría simplemente declarando el tipo.

```
Definir Nombres Como Caracter
Definir Apellidos Como Caracter
```

En segundo lugar, al ser estos caracteres tu condicional debe cambiar a esta:

```
Si Nombres[contador1]+" "+Apellidos[contador1] == "Ricardo Gutierrez"  Entonces
```

Otra nota, a tu auxiliar le estas asignando un contador que no va dentro del contexto, por lo cual se solucionaría de la siguiente manera.

```
aux<-contador1
```